# How to put image on pdf-dc% in Racket

Tags: pdf, graphics, racket

I have following code to create a pdf file:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define dc
  (new pdf-dc%
    [interactive #f]
    [use-paper-bbox #f]
    [width  500]
    [height 800]
    [output "testfile.pdf"]))

(send dc start-doc "file output")
(send dc start-page)

(send dc draw-text "Test Text" 100 100)
(send dc draw-line 100 100 200 200)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

And I can draw ellipse, rectangle etc as given on this page: https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html

However, I could not find how to put images (jpg / png / bmp) here. I tried:

```
(send dc draw-bitmap "mypict.jpg" 200 200) ;; NOT WORKING;
```

But it does not work. The error is:

```
draw-bitmap: contract violation
  expected: (is-a?/c bitmap%)
  given: "mypict.jpg"
  in: the 1st argument of
      (->*m
       ((is-a?/c bitmap%) real? real?)
       ((or/c 'solid 'opaque 'xor)
        (is-a?/c color%)
        (or/c (is-a?/c bitmap%) #f))
       boolean?)
  contract from: (class pdf-dc%)
```

Following statement runs without any error but how can I insert filename in it?

```
(send dc draw-bitmap (make-object bitmap% 100 100) 200 200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `"mypict.jpg"` is a string, not a `bitmap%`.

```
(make-object bitmap% "mypict.jpg")
```

will create a proper bitmap object for you.

Comment: Yes, it works. Can I set its size (width, height) on page? This page https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html has width and height as required parameters to create a bitmap% object.

Comment: There are three variations of `(make-object bitmap% ...)`. Here the argument is a string, so look at the second paragraph in the docs. There is no height and width, since the size is stored in the jpg-file.

Comment: Can I shrink or expand this image on page so that it shows as smaller or larger?

Comment: You can scale the drawing context pdf-dc before drawing the bitmap.